# Dynamic Mapping of dynamic JSON data conversion in java

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring, logic

i have stucked in on issue
i wanted to do dynamic mapping of json data which is also changing
**problem is** :
suppose data comming from 3 api so i have created demo data

```
{
    "api1": [
        {
            "jid":101,
            "clientName":"ABC"
        },
        {
            "jid": 102,
            "clientName": "XYZ"
        }
    ],
    "api2":[
        {
            "jobId":1101,
            "jClientName": "ABCD"
        },
        {
            "jobId": 1102,
            "jClientName": "XYZA"
        }
    ],
    "api3":[
        {
            "id":19001,
            "jobCName":"ABCDEF"
        },
        {
            "id": 19002,
            "jobCName": "PQRSTU"
        }
    ]
}
```

in this data each api have 2 records i want to map that data into following given format,

```
[
    {
        "jobid":101,
        "clientName":"ABC"
    },
    {
        "jobid": 102,
        "clientName": "ABCD"
    },
    {
        "jobid": 1101,
        "clientName": "ABCDEF"
    }
]
```

so all data should be map correctly,
first api have clientName, second have jClientName and 3rd api have jobCName these field can be dynamic but i want them to be mapped correctly in clientName column
how can i solve this issue, what approch or what should i do

need response in this format that each field should mapped correctly
expected output is:

```
[
    {
        "jobid":101,
        "clientName":"ABC"
    },
    {
        "jobid": 102,
        "clientName": "ABCD"
    },
    {
        "jobid": 1101,
        "clientName": "ABCDEF"
    }
]
```

what logic should be implemented for this

Comment: I don't understand the logic you want to achieve. Have you mistyped the keys in the expected output?   And wouldn't there be 6 items in the output array?

Comment: There are no mistyped keys,
actually, i have multiple JSON data some have id as "jid" some have id as "jobid" keys can be anything I want to map that json filed id to my son format which have key jobid
wether API have jid or jobid it should map to jobid and I have multiple json which have diff keyname but at end I want all to jobid key of my json

Answer (score -1):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode jsonData = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

        List<Map<String, String>> finalData = new ArrayList<>();
        for (JsonNode apiData : jsonData) {
            for (JsonNode record : apiData) {
                Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<>();
                if (record.has("jid")) {
                    data.put("jobid", record.get("jid").asText());
                    data.put("clientName", record.get("clientName").asText());
                } else if (record.has("jobId")) {
                    data.put("jobid", record.get("jobId").asText());
                    data.put("clientName", record.get("jClientName").asText());
                } else if (record.has("id")) {
                    data.put("jobid", record.get("id").asText());
                    data.put("clientName", record.get("jobCName").asText());
                }
                finalData.add(data);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(finalData);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide you answer within Stackoverflow, not on your own blog.   For one thing the code you gave is quite unreadable

Comment: thanks a lot Virendra Kumawat this can work but, may be my json data will change and instead of "jid" there will be "newJobId" or "submittalJobId" so keys can change, so for every key I need to write else if statement, how can I make it dynamically that it will work for every key? should I make array of keys or else ?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).